# When can an iterable be replaced with an iterator?

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to understand in which situations an *iterable* can be replaced with an *iterator* in Python 3.

More specifically, consider this example:

```
ml = [1,2,3,4]

iter_ml = iter(ml)

deq_ml = collections.deque(ml)
deq_iter_ml = collections.deque(iter_ml)

print(ml)
print(iter_ml)
print(deq_ml)
print(deq_iter_ml)
```

This produces the output

```
[1, 2, 3, 4]
<list_iterator object at 0x7f6ee8eef4c0>
deque([1, 2, 3, 4])
deque([1, 2, 3, 4])
```

If I check the documentation of `deque`, it accepts an iterable as the first argument. But here when I provided an iterator over the iterable, that worked too

However, it didn't work when the iterator is given to `print`

Same is the confusion with `islice`. It works with both iterables and iterators.

How to know if those can be used interchangeably?

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9884132/what-exactly-are-iterator-iterable-and-iteration) can help.

Comment: What do you mean it didn't work with print? Print does print the iterator's representation, just as it prints the iterable's. Although note that the iterator can only be consumed _once_, so print gets an _empty_ iterator (not that it matters here).

Comment: @jonrsharpe , what I meant was that `print` didn't print the list. While `deque` worked with both `iterable` or and `iterator` over that iterable

Comment: It did print the list. If you mean it didn't print the items from the iterator, then I'd note that you didn't ask it to, you asked it to print _the iterator itself_ (which was actually empty at that point anyway). `deque` _iterates over_ the argument, so anything iterable (which iterators are) can be consumed.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I think my confusion was stemming from the question that would be the behavior when `iter` is called on `iterator`. Calling `iter` on `iterable` returns and `iterator` which `deque` and `islice` would be doing internally. But I think I got my answer. Since `iter` on `iterator` return `self`, the methods which operate on an `iterable` would still work fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for the links and comments.

**I think the source of my confusion was this:**

Calling `iter` on `iterable` will return an `iterator`.

But what would be the behavior when `iter` was called on an `iterator`. As that would be the case when I replace `iterable` with `iterator` in `deque` and `islice`

**Confusion cleared**

As, one the [links](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63781053/3821298) from the comments above state

> An ITERATOR is an object that is self-iterable (meaning that it has an **iter** method that returns self).

I got my answer. Also this class [post](https://nvie.com/posts/iterators-vs-generators/) by Vincent nicely depicts that each `iterator` is always an `iterable`.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

An itera*ble* is any type that implements `__iter__`. [An itera*tor* is a *specific* kind of iterable, namely one that also implements `__next__`.](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#typeiter)
As such, an iterator can be used anywhere an iterable is expected.
Usually, that means *iterating* something to get values: `for` loops, `list`/`tuple`/`deque`/... constructors, iterator tools like `map`, and more.

However, that does not mean that an iterator is the *exact same* thing as *any* iterable. For example, a `list` is an iterable and a `list`'s iterator is an iterable, but they are two distinct objects.

```py
>>> from collections.abc import Iterable
>>> l = [0, 1, 4, 9, 16]
>>> isinstance(l, Iterable)
True
>>> isinstance(iter(l), Iterable)
True
>>> l is iter(l)
False
```

As a comparison, both `3` and `3.0` are *numbers*. They represent the same value, can often be used interchangeably and one can convert from one to the other. However, they are still distinct things and do look and behave differently in many contexts – for example, being displayed differently.